# How to make first key value default checked using php

Tags: php, html

Here i have one array , i want to make first key value default checked using php ,

> My array ---   print_r($compoItem);

```
  Array
(
    [0] => Rice+chapathi
    [1] => Chappathi
    [2] => Pepsi
    [3] => 7up
)
```

> My HTML

```
<?php
    $compoItem = explode(',',$sql2['combo']);

    foreach($compoItem as $comValues)
    {
    ?>
    <div class="radio">

      <ul><input type="radio" name="optradio" checked=""><?php echo $comValues?></ul>

     </div>
      <?php } ?>
```

Here last keu value is deafult checked but for me don't want last value i want key value is default checked , how can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Echo the attribute based on the index in the array.

```
<?php
    $compoItem = explode(',',$sql2['combo']);    
    foreach($compoItem as $i => $comValues){
    //                 ---^^^^^---
?>
<div class="radio">    
  <ul><input type="radio" name="optradio" <?php if($i == 0){ echo 'checked="checked"'; }?>><?php echo $comValues?></ul>    
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I got the solution

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $compoItem = explode(',',$sql2['combo']);
    $first = true;

    foreach ( $compoItem as $comValues )
    {
       $checked = ( $first ) ? 'checked="checked"' : "";
    ?>



     <div class="radio">

          <ul><input type="radio" name="optradio" <?php echo $checked; ?>><?php echo $comValues?></ul>

     </div>
<?php 
       $first = false;
     } ?>
```